Can we generate nested API document in Swagger / C#?
I have controller action method in C#:
[HttpPost]
[SwaggerRequestExample(typeof(string), typeof(BookExample))]
public async Task<ActionResult> SubmitBookAsync([FromBody] string rawRequest)
{
    var response = await _cdsHookSvc.SubmitBookAsync(rawRequest);
        
    return response;
}

SubmitBookAsync internally is calling a third-party POST API call UpdateBookInventoryAsync(request).
I would like get the Swagger document of SubmitBookAsync and UpdateBookInventoryAsync.
I'm getting SubmitBookAsync Swagger API document - that's easy.
Not sure how to get UpdateBookInventoryAsync Swagger API document...
Purpose: testing team wants to investigate UpdateBookInventoryAsync updated request.
